# Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'getter'

Tags: kotlin

I have something like this in the code

```
var barCode: BarCode? = null
```

now getBarCode() is defined in the interface - then I get the error that this might be an accidental override. unfortunately this does not work:

```
var barCode: BarCode? = null
override get
```

I could do something like this:

```
private var barCode: BarCode? = null

override fun getBarCode(): BarCode? = barCode
fun setBarCode(barCode: BarCode) {
    this.barCode = barCode
}
```

but this looks like way to many likes and verbosity for kotlin - there must be a shorter way - especially as this pattern will repeat multiple times in this class

Comment: And the interface is out of your control? You cannot convert the method in the interface to a property?

Comment: the interface is java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Kotlin 1.0, there is no shorter way: a method `getBarCode()` in a Java interface needs to be implemented by a method named `getBarCode()` in Kotlin, not by a property named `barCode`.

There's [an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6653) requesting to make it possible to override Java methods with properties; you can vote for it to get notifications of updates.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info!